# Limit and integral properties of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= c$.
Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(s)\;ds = c$.

I've tried splitting the integral into $\int_0^M+ \int_M^x$ but I don't really know where to go from there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital?

Comment: Splitting the integral as you have will work.  For $\epsilon > 0$ choose $M$ so that $c - \epsilon < f(s) < c +\epsilon$ for all $s \geq M$, then use this in your integrals.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra I believe we are, yes.

Comment: This is the continuous version of the following result on sequences : if $a_{n} \to L$ then $(1/n)\sum_{k = 1}^{n}a_{k} \to L$. As noted by Barry Cipra, the proof follows by a single application of LHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and find some $x_{0}$ with $x>x_{0}\Rightarrow c-\varepsilon\leq f\left(x\right)\leq c+\varepsilon$.

Then for $x>x_0$: $$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(s\right)ds+\left(c-\varepsilon\right)\left(1-\frac{x_{0}}{x}\right)\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f\left(s\right)ds\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(s\right)ds+\left(c+\varepsilon\right)\left(1-\frac{x_{0}}{x}\right)$$

If $x\rightarrow\infty$ then the left side goes to $c-\varepsilon$
and the right side to $c+\varepsilon$.

This can be done for every $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c \neq 0$, then notice that $\int_0^x f(s)\;ds$ approaches $\pm\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. So your limit is an indeterminate form of type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: By this reasoning $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x}$ would be indeterminate too.

Comment: OK.${}{}{}{}{}$